i am facing error during the runtime of neovim when lazyvim tries to install treesitter parser
I am new to neovim so I tried lazyvim and I followed all the step recomended by lazyvim. I am in windows and all the things are working properly but I am having problem with downloading treesitter parser .
I tried WinGW but it didn't work and I tried other option such as zig and visual studio but it also didn't work. LLVM seems to work somewhat but I am still having error just in case I have tried all the thing suggested in GitHub windows support. I also tired other method suggested such as
but it still didn't work I am facing still facing the same problem.
(https://i.sstatic.net/2fPJU9uM.png)
(https://i.sstatic.net/19gYUoi3.png)
(https://i.sstatic.net/F02pXwPV.png)
what do you need to solve this problem please somebody help me I don't know what I am doing wrong
